# Supremum property confirmation

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Hi this is a very short question, I'm afraid this post might get deleted because it's too short. I was wondering if this is true: (in an intro analysis course)

$$\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R},\ \ \sup(f(x)-f(y))\leq |f(x)-f(y)|$$ 
Is this inequality always true?

If it is could someone show me a proof of this? Thank you!

Comment: What is the norm $\|\cdot\|$ here?

Comment: Oh sorry, should be absolute values, will change that right away.

Comment: You're (presumably) using $x$ and $y$ twice here in two different ways: once for the dummy variables in the supremum (i.e. $\sup_{x,y\in \mathbb{R}}\dots$) and another time unbound from that, and I assume you're talking about this being true for all $x$ and $y$ in that context?

Comment: It's true that for all $a, b\in \mathbb{R}$, $\sup_{x,y\in \mathbb{R}}(\left|f(x)-f(y)\right|) \geq |f(a)-f(b)|$, if that's anything close to what you're after. Depending on what exactly you meant by this question (you could be saying that there exists a particular $x$ and want to know whether this holds for all $y$, or you could want for all $x,y$, or if there exist such $x,y$, etc), I'm pretty sure this statement is false in general.

Comment: I found the answer. Since the supremum is the value when the difference is the biggest, that inequality is true. That's just by definition of supremum.